# Remove redundant implementations of an interface without using inheritance

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a design problem that I can't seem to figure out. I am implementing a card game and I am struggling with how to organize the structure of the cards. Every card in the game has some shared behavior which means Card should be the base class.

However, each card can be either a Coin, Mana, or Health card. On top of that any Card could be a combination of these three types. My original thought was to make Coin, Mana, and Health each an interface and then I would be able to implement any Card with the relevent interfaces like so:

```
public class SomeCard extends Card implements Coin, Mana {

}
```

Through this way all inherited classes would have the base Card behavior and implement the necessary behavior. The problem arises from the fact that there is some shared behavior within each of the three interfaces. For example with Coin there is a getWorth() function that is essentially the same for all Coin Cards. If I have the same exact function & implementation then there should be a way to abstract out the redundancy. This is just one example of the redundancy.

```
public class CardA extends Card implements Coin {
    public int getWorth(){
        return worth;
    }

    //Other inherited or implemented methods
}

public class CardB extends Card implements Coin, Health {

    public int getWorth(){
        return worth;
    }

    //Other inherited or implemented methods
}
```

Unfortunately since Coin is an interface there is no way to reduce this redundancy across all the cards. Is there a way to remove that redundant code while also applying a Coin, Mana, Health type or some combination of those?

I want to avoid something like this:

```
public class SomeCard extends CoinManaCard {

}
```

I think the above would be a really poor implementation because whenever a new type is added there would be many more combinations of types and the maintenance would be significant.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What you're looking for is interface default implementations, which will be available in Java 8.

Comment: Yup that should do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shared behavior can be moved to a superclass. If you can't modify Card for some reason, you can introduce another level of inheritance -- in my environment we'd typically call it something like BaseCard -- which either implements all the methods of Card (you can override them again in the specific card classes) or which is an `abstract class` so it can just implement the shared behaviors and leaves the others to be implemented by classes derived from it. Then your actual CardA, CardB, etcetera would extended BaseCard, which would also make them Cards.

(Note that you almost answered this yourself when you used the word "abstract". When there's shared behavior you want to factor out, another layer of inheritance is one way to do it, and abstract classes are a good way to keep that relatively easy and make it clear that you don't intend them to be used directly.)

The other solution would be delegation -- change the is-a relationship to has-a, have each card own an instance of a utility class which provides the shared functionality, and have the card's methods call methods on that utility class to do the job. Again, that lets you factor out a set of logic, but this operates entirely independently of inheritance. It's a bit less efficient, but it's a perfectly reasonable solution. And if you need to pick up behavior from several different classes it's the only solution, since Java only allows multiple inheritance for interfaces, not for classes (even if they're abstract) -- one superclass (with whatever inheritance it has), plus as many interfaces as make sense.

(If you want to know why Java had that restriction, look up "diamond inheritance". The simple answer is that it can get very messy very quickly, and even in languages which support it people often wind up using something more like Java's single-inheritance-plus-interfaces-plus-delegation model.)